# Simple if statement with modulo operator

Tags: python

Newcomer to coding, I've decided to go through problemsets on codeforces to help build my experience and understanding. I've decided to use python as my first programming language. I'm stuck on a question that I'm so sure I'm right but I can't seem to understand where the computer finds I'm wrong.

[website link](http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/4/A?csrf_token=261101dec4580bd4244f455034d432d0)

TL;DR

**Input**

The first *(and the only)* input line contains integer number w (1 ≤ w ≤ 100) — the weight of the watermelon bought by the boys.

**Output**

Print YES, if the boys can divide the watermelon into two parts, each of them weighing even number of kilos; and NO in the opposite case.

I've decided to tackle this problem using an if statement and modulo:

```
if w % 2 == 0: 
    print('YES')
```

I've run this through the python shell and every time **w** is even it will print YES and if not will have no output. Yet when I submit the code it says wrong answer on test 1...

EDIT: does 'only one input line' condition mean that I have to put all my if and else statements on one line?

Comment: You do know about the `else` part of an `if`?

Comment: what about 'NO' case? You haven't thought through the question completely.

Comment: ok...but the only output allowed is YES, so if I include an else statement that produces an NO that doesn't comply with the question

Comment: How does it not comply if the question says "and NO in the opposite case"?

Comment: oh that's what it meant. I saw that it didn't write 'print NO' and I assumed otherwise

Comment: Also keep in mind that if `w` is exactly `2`, you need to print 'NO', according to the question, as you can't split `2` into 2 even numbers.

Every even number `>2` is fine though, as any even number > 2 can be made by adding two other even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `else` statement which prints NO in the opposite case:

```
...
else:
    print('NO')
```

With that said, if you read the question properly it says

> each of them weighing even number of kilos

To get two pieces, each weighting an even number of kilos you need to compute `w> 2 and w % 4 == 0` (see comments for why):

```
if w > 2 and w % 4 == 0: 
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: why should I compute w % 4 == 0? If the watermelon weighs 2 kilos only, then that statement would prove false.

Comment: If the watermelon weights 2 kilos. Then by splitting it in two you get two pieces, eight weighting 1 kilo. 1 is an odd number, but the question says "an even number of kilos", hence 2 should print "NO". Unless ofcourse by "an even number" you actually mean "an integer number".

Comment: yes, you are right. Another question is everytime I submit my code, the computer spits 'exit code is 1' what does this mean?

Comment: @JonasAdler you're still wrong about the `% 4` part. While `2` is not a valid answer, as you can't split it into even numbers, `6`, for example, is, despite `6 % 4` not being 0, since you can split 6kg into 2kg+4kg. The question explicitly states that the pieces need not be the same size.

So `if w > 2 and w % 2==0` would be a valid condition for "YES" case

Comment: You are indeed correct `Zinki`. I guess the general solution would be `w > 2 and w % 2 == 0`, right? Edit: Your edit got it.